# When to use CSS and JSX styles in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I am learning React and realized that you can use either real CSS by importing a CSS file, or you can use JS which has CSS-like code using camel cases.

Example for pure CSS: `import './AppStyle.css'` which contains `background-color: black;`

Example for JS version: `const AppStyle = { backgroundColor: "black" }`

Which one is better to use and why? Or maybe they’re both fine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Writing CSS allows all the benefits of CSS (like selectors, media query).
- In inline styles, you write Object-like styles vs. actual CSS.
- Code readability is worst in inline style implementation, while managing styles using the CSS is easy to maintain.
- The inline styles take more space in DOM because all the styles are defined internally along with the DOM element, while CSS is described separately, creating no issues for the compiler while compiling the file.

Comment: Thank you! You answered my question perfectly!

Comment: In 4 minutes when it allows me to say this answered my question, I will.

Answer (score 1):

There is ups and down with both solutions, you can achieve the same result with both, so it comes down to you want styling solution you prefer

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience,JSX and CSS are different technologies to solve the styling problem.

Good points of css:

- css selectors
- styling into css files

Good points of js:

- js into styling -> sometimes you want to calculate styles over js https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-rule-value-function/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.3#enables-functions-for-dynamic-styles
- more approaches to solve one problem -> it has js

Recommendation: Try to use one, it reduce the complexity and documentation to read.